# Google Chrome Devtools broken when inspecting Android Webview

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, android-webview, google-chrome-devtools

This worked well and the problem started happenning about two weeks ago.

I run a Chrome on a Windows 10 computer. I have already tried uninstalling, and then reinstalling Chrome since the issue started. No change.

This is what happens:

1) I start Android emulator
2) Run my cordova app in it
3) Go to chrome://inspect and click on the link for my running app on emulator. It is listed ok, that works.
4) The DevTools window opens, but it does not show all the information as it did. I see half of the screen blank. The menu tabs sometimes don't show, I have to minimize, then maximize, then they *MAY* show. 
There are no scrollbars for any of the content panels so I cannot actually see anything useful.

I tried clicking on the gear icon in the top right of the screen, to open Settings, and see if changing something there would fix it. Nothing. The settings window opens but it will ONLY show the links on the left to the settings areas. The right side where the settings controls should be, is completely blank.

[image]

[image]

I have created a new emulator and the same happened.

I have Android Studio 3.0.1

I tried inspecting the devtools with shift-ctrl-j

It is showing some strange errors. As if it was loading an older version of itself:

[image]

Please help, I need to use this to debug my cordova app during development and I don't know what else to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/s47cbyLKvxA

I haven't digested the thread fully, but I think it's due to a deprecation in Chrome that is outside of the DevTools team's control.

Please let us know if this is indeed the same issue that you're seeing.

Comment: Yes it is the same issue! It is very strange. I now tried creating one Android emulator running Android 7, and the DevTools work ok with that one. If I create an emulator with Android 6, I experience the issue. So devtools for older Android versions is broken now? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, same issue with me... hope that they do something about it some day.

Comment: Its ironical that one of the world's "supposedly" best software companies yields/ships out these kinds of products. Android Studio is already a shame and one of the worst native mobile development IDE's to be built (tainting good old Intellij's name in the midst of it) and to add to the misery of a typical Android dev, even chrome inspector is all up in the air. This does sound like ranting but seriously give us a break.

Answer (score 17):

As explained in [Kayce Basques's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000682/3527940), this is due to a problem with versions of Chrome since 63.

The solution is to use an older version of Chromium.

Here are the download links for the the latest version of Chromium  (version 62.0.3202.94, branch base position 499098) which support it:

- macOS: https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Mac%2F499098%2Fchrome-mac.zip?generation=1504230238091965&alt=media
- Windows 64 bits: https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Win_x64%2F499095%2Fchrome-win32.zip?generation=1504230103809077&alt=media

Feel free to edit this post to add the links for other platforms.

Comment: How did you found these specific binaries?

Comment: Followed the link trail from the link in the other answer. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/qWg3OAGUIOY/KdvsoSGOBgAJ explains you need a version before M63. https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium gives the convoluted way to find a specific build.

Comment: Didn't work for me, Dev Tools is not opening in that version.

Comment: What is the version of Android and that of Chrome on the target device (the one you want to debug)?

Comment: Wow, didn't expect and answer! Thank you sir! I'm using an emulator for Android 6 and there is no Chrome/Chromium on the phone, just a 'Browser' app, which has no version in settings

Comment: Do you see the emulator and the browser show up in the list in `chrome://inspect`? Does `adb devices` correctly show the simulator? What OS are you running on?

Comment: I can see the emulator in adb devices. In Chromium when i open the chrome://inspect i get "Something went wrong while displaying this web page." . Trying to open the dev tools, it popped for 1 sec and then closed. I'm using mac OS

Comment: I get the same issue now. I wonder if this couldn't be related to the macOS version, I recently upgraded to Catalina. Obviously this isn't quite supported any more. I believe your option is to use the regular Chrome. The remote dev tools are very broken and barely usable when targeting an old version of Chrome but they should still be somewhat usable. Note that normal users with Android >= 5 should have a recent Chrome, contrary to the simulator.