# Chrome Developer Tools for a device messed up

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For the last 2 months, Chrome Developer Tools when inspecting a webpage of an Android device on Windows, is completely messed up and unusable. Inspecting a regular website is fine. I tried reinstalling Chrome. Examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just verified, i have it normal here, which version(s) do you have?

Comment: @Kaddath 63.0.3239.132

Comment: same here (64bits).. have you got chrome plugins installed?

Comment: @Kaddath I had a couple of extensions, but I disabled them, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 6):

Issue seems only with emulator with Android 6 or lower. Got this from comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000682/428724.